# Python request from Amazon EC2 instance

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, python-requests

I am developing an app that scrapes data from an e-commerce website. When I send request using python's `requests` module from my personal system I get the required response.

```
import requests
response = requests.get('https://www.daraz.com.np/televisions/?ajax=true&page=1')
print(response.text)
```

The response text is

```
{"mods":{"filter":{"tItemType":"nt_filter","filterItems":[{"options":[{"value":"televisions","title":"Televisions","url":"/televisions/","order":0,"id":"198"}]
```

But when I send the same request from an EC2 instance I get the following error

```
{"ret":["FAIL_SYS_TRAFFIC_LIMIT::哎哟喂,被挤爆啦,请稍后重试!","RGV587_ERROR::SM::哎哟喂,被挤爆啦,请稍后重试!"], "data":{"url":"https://bixi.alicdn.com/punish/34889.html?uuid=522fb26767e56c4470fdb73b10ae1754&action=deny"}}
```

Comment: Obviously they have some kind of scraping protection in place, possibly something that bans AWS IPs. It is also possible that another instance from the same subnet is hitting them hard.

Comment: According to Google Translate... `Ouch, it's squeezed, please try again later` and the `url` specifies `action=deny`. I'd assume they've blocked Amazon EC2 ranges from doing this.

Comment: So the only solution would be to use a proxy.

Comment: You may first try using a different EC2 instance in a different availability zone.

Comment: Yes I've tried this in three different servers.

Comment: , did you tried the same thing with lambda function? try that,also try to proxy your AWS requests through some commercial VPN maybe, home/work network, or something that is not blacklisted.